# There are $n$ - cells, $n$ - white balls ,$n$ - black balls. Divide $2$ balls into each cell Find the probability$j-$cell has $2$ same color balls.

Tags: probability

There are $n$ - cells, $n$ - white balls ,$n$ - black balls.

Divide $2$ balls into each cell.

Find the probability that the $j-$cell has $2$ same color balls.

I don't know how to deal with the fact that n black balls are the same and so are white balls.

Let's look a the first cell, divide one ball, suppose it is a black one.

The probability dividing another black ball into the first cell is $\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$.

We can do the same thing with the white balls so we get $2\cdot\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$.

My problem is how I find the many possibilities of the other cells after I divide 2 of the same color balls in the first cell.

It is not $n \choose 2$ since the balls are the same.

Help, please.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Whichever color ball is the first into cell $j$, each of the other balls is equally likely to be the other ball in cell $j$.  There are $2n-1$ balls remaining, of which $n-1$ are the same color as the first ball, so the probability that both balls are the same color is $\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$.